# Inheritance and is_detected_v provides a strange result (C++17)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have simplified version of code:

```
#include <experimental/type_traits>

template<class T> using has_data_t = decltype(T::data());

template <class B> constexpr auto get_data() {
    return std::experimental::is_detected_v<has_data_t, B>;
}
    
template <typename Topt> struct opt_base {
    static constexpr bool i = get_data<Topt>();
  //static constexpr auto j = get_data<Topt>(); // fail to compile
};

struct opt : public opt_base<opt> {
    static int data() { return 7;}
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::experimental::is_detected_v<has_data_t, opt>);
}
```

This code compiles. But if you will uncomment commented line then assert fails. It was tested with GCC 7.1 and Clang 4.0.0. Compilation parameters: -std=c++1z -O3 -Wall.
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/4RuSdS)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this code:

```
static constexpr bool i = get_data<Topt>();
static constexpr auto j = get_data<Topt>();
```

`Topt` (that is, `opt`) isn't complete yet. So `is_detected_v<has_data_t, opt>` is should be `false`. But by the time we get to `main`, `opt` *is* complete. And so we'd expect `is_detected_v<has_data_t, opt>` to be `true`.

Having a template that when instantiated in different contexts yields different results means that your program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. See [temp.point]:

> A specialization for any template may have points of instantiation in multiple translation units. If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

The addition of `j` doesn't really matter - it just happened to flip the switch that changed the order of the way the compiler chose to instantiate things. The program is ill-formed regardless of the presence of `j`.

Comment: What name is nondependent here?

Comment: @T.C Hm. Do none of those examples in the notes apply here, or is this the wrong text entirely? Pretty sure the example is ill-formed ndr for some reason.

Comment: I think [\[temp.point\]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.point#8) is more relevant.